# An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketAcl operation: Unknown

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I got this exception when calling the method put_bucket_acl(**kwargs) of boto3.client to set bucket acl. (PS: it's a bucket of ceph object instead of aws)

---

My code :

```
import boto3
import copy

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
        aws_access_key_id=s3_conf['ak'], 
        aws_secret_access_key=s3_conf['sk'], 
        endpoint_url=s3_conf["host"])
bucket_acl = s3.BucketAcl(test_bucket)
bucket_acl.grants.append(new_grants)
bucket_acl.put(ACL='private', AccessControlPolicy={'Grants': bucket_acl.grants, 'Owner': bucket_acl.owner})
```

I also try Session.client:

```
session = Session(s3_conf["ak"], s3_conf["sk"])
s3 = session.resource("s3", endpoint_url=s3_conf["host"])
s3_client = session.client("s3", endpoint_url=s3_conf["host"])

rsp = s3_client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=test_bucket)
old_access_control_policy = { 'Grants': copy.deepcopy(rsp['Grants']), 'Owner': copy.deepcopy(rsp['Owner']) }
new_access_control_policy = copy.deepcopy(old_access_control_policy)
new_access_control_policy['Grants'].append(new_grants)
s3_client.put_bucket_acl(Bucket=test_bucket, ACL='private', AccessControlPolicy=old_access_control_policy)
```

if I remove the param AccessControlPolicy, it runs succeed

```
s3_client.put_bucket_acl(Bucket=test_bucket, ACL='private')
```

Am I call this method in a wrong way? 
But the guide also call this call this method in same way :https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_acl
Thinks for any help.

Comment: I got the same error, I accidentally set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY value to AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="I set the access key ID here" ; export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="I set secret access key here") and vice versa. 
Reversing values fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to set bucket acl like:

```
s3_client.put_bucket_acl(Bucket=test_bucket, AccessControlPolicy={...})
```

ACL and AccessControlPolicy are AccessControlList and the parameter AccessControlList can only be one of: ACL, AccessControlPolicy, Bucket, ContentMD5, GrantFullControl, GrantRead, GrantReadACP, GrantWrite, GrantWriteACP. Later I need to read the code of botocore and find the difference between ceph s3 and amazon s3. Think for reading.